# Factoring Polynomials into Galois Conjugate Linear Factors

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, galois-theory, factoring

Let $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a polynomial of degree $n$.

Question: Is there a nice way to describe the set of polynomials $f(x)$ (not necessarily monic) that can be factored as $f(x)= \prod_{i = 1}^n (\beta_i x - \alpha_i)$ over the splitting field in such a way that the factors are Galois conjugates of each other?

What I know: Evidently, if $f_0 = 1$, we can take $\beta_i = 1$ and the factors $(x - \alpha_i)$ are Galois conjugates of each other. Also, there are polynomials $f(x)$ that fail to satisfy this property, like $f(x) = 2x^2 - 5$.

Comment: Remember that you're in a splitting field of $f$

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg Thanks, your comment made me realize I had incorrectly worded the question!

Comment: A necessary condition is that $f(x)$ is a power of an irreducible polynomial. In (say) the irreducible case, the condition is equivalent to asking that the leading coefficient is a norm from $K = \mathbf{Q}[x]/f(x)$ to $\mathbf{Q}$. This is not going to have any simpler characterization.

Comment: @user670344 Why is it equivalent to the leading coefficient being a norm? I agree that the leading coefficient must be a norm, but I don't see why the desired factorization exists if the leading coefficient is a norm.

Comment: If $a = N_{K/\mathbf{Q}}(\lambda)$ for $K = \mathbf{Q}(\alpha)$, then the product of the conjugates of $\lambda (x - \alpha)$ will be $f(x)$.

Comment: Oh, right, silly me!